# MSBuild Force Item Include to be treated as custom/literal

Tags: msbuild

I am defining my own Item in and ItemGroup where I have custom values that I don't want to be evaluated to paths

When I try to do transforms, the ./ is being treated as a path and so I only get a single item for transforms and batching.

How can I force the . at the end to be treated as a literal?

Comment: For using special characters in `Include` attribute you can use hexadecimal representations of `ASCII` characters. See: [Special characters to escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/special-characters-to-escape). `.` isn't listed in example, but i think it makes sense to try `%2e` for escaping.

Comment: Please ping me If it helped, then I move the comment to the answer.

Comment: that worked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using special characters in the `Include` attribute you can use the hexadecimal representations of the `ASCII` characters. For example the symbol `.` will be represents as `2e`. The percent symbol always precedes the hexadecimal representation: `%2e`.

> You can get the full list of special characters to escape from the
>   [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/special-characters-to-escape).

---

[Special characters to escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/special-characters-to-escape) | [ASCII to Hex text converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html)